# PHP/MySQL Update and Insert based on two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have been going over this for a few days now and keep reaching stumbling blocks. I am trying to select a unique id from table2 and match it against an id in table1. If the id is matched, update the row in table1 and remove the record from table2. If there is no match then insert the record into table1.

I have got to a point where I can update the records and insert the new ones but I cannot seem to delete the matched record before the insert therefore creating a duplicate. I have tried a delete join query after the update but because the new logon_id has a character prepended to it, it no longer matches in table2.

I was doing an update join before for updates but I had too many queries going on so trying to keep it simple.

Any advice? Still a newb at this game.

```
$table2_query   =   "SELECT * FROM table2";
$table2_result  =   mysql_query($table2_query);
$table2_count   =   mysql_num_rows($table2_result);

    if($table2_count == 0)      {

        if(mysql_error())   {
        echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();   
        }

    }

while($table2_row = mysql_fetch_array($table2_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))     {

    $check_number_length = strlen($table2_row['unique_id']);

        if($check_number_length < 7)    {

            if(substr($table2_row['unique_id'], 0, 2) < 35) {
                $logon_id   = 'n' . $table2_row['unique_id'];
            }else   {
                $logon_id   = 'v' . $table2_row['unique_id'];
            }

        }else   {
            $logon_id   = $table2_row['unique_id'];
        }

    // Set variables for insert query for creation of a new user record
    $first_name     = $table2_row['firstname'];
    $last_name          = $table2_row['lastname'];
    $email_address  = $table2_row['email'];


    $duplicates_query   = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE '$logon_id' = logon_id";
    $duplicates_result  = mysql_query($duplicates_query);
    $duplicates_row = mysql_fetch_array($duplicates_result);
    $duplicates_count   = mysql_num_rows($duplicates_result);

        if($duplicates_count == 0)  {

            if(mysql_error())   {
            echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();   
            }

        }else   {
            $update_records_query       =   "UPDATE table1 SET first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', email_address='$email_address'";
            $update_records_result      =   mysql_query($update_records_query);
            $update_records_count       =   mysql_affected_rows();
            echo $update_records_count;
        }

    $create_records_query = "INSERT INTO table1 (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
    $create_records_result  =   mysql_query($create_records_query);
    $create_records_count   =   mysql_affected_rows();

        if($create_records_count == 0){

            if(mysql_error()){
                echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();   
            }   
        }

    echo $create_records_count . ' record(s) created.';

}
```

Comment: Please, do a "more-clean" sample.

Comment: so, what makes you unable to run that DELETE query?

Comment: Sorry @GabrielSantos tried to make it as clean as possible but wanted to make sure that everything could be stepped through. I have removed a lot of the extraneous stuff, apologies.

Comment: Do things like `if($table2_count == 0) { // SHOW ERROR }`

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Well after the update I did a delete join query to remove users from table2 that matched the id I had just inserted into table1 except when I perform the insert it's prepended with a character which does not exist in table2 hence I cannot find the record to remove it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what's the point in doing JOIN delete? why can't you do just straight delete?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Can you provide an example? Would it just be "DELETE table2 FROM table2"?

Comment: What example you need? Why don't you need a join to select a record, but need it to delete EXACTLY THE SAME record?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Apologies for being dim but i'm still a newb so you may need to clarify so it sinks in :-) Sorry.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel If you can help, that would be great. As mentioned i'm still new to the PHP game and sometimes struggle with basic logical thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $res = mysql_query ("SELECT count(table1.login_id) AS count FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.login_id = table1.login_id WHERE table2.login_id = \"".$login_id."\";") or die ("Error joining tables"); 
    /*joins both tables together and selects both id's from tables */

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); // should only return one row so grab first

    if ($row['count'] > 0) { // check if id exists in both tables (duplicates)
             // updates rows from one table into another
             mysql_query('UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.username = table2.username, table1.password = table2.password, table1.email = table2.email WHERE table1.login_id = "'.$login_id.'" AND table2.login_id = "'.$login_id.'";') or die ("error updating table1");

            //delete old row
             mysql_query('DELETE FROM table2 WHERE login_id = "'.$login_id.'";') or die("error deleting from table2");


    }else { // if id doesn't exist in table1
            mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table1(username,password,email) SELECT username,password,email FROM table2 where login_id = '".$login_id."';") or die ("error inserting into table1");
    }
```

remove the n at the beginning of login_id on table1

```
UPDATE table1 set login_id = replace(login_id,"n","");
```

new update query if remove n at begin of login_id

```
mysql_query ('UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.username = table2.username, table1.password = table2.password, table1.email = table2.email WHERE table1.login_id = table2.login_id AND table1.login_id = "'.$login_id.'";');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have not yet tried but will the update, delete and insert actually work? The $logon_id var is going to have the logon_id from table2 prepended with a character so am I actually going to be able to find it using the WHERE? E.g. table2 logon id = 123456, table1 is n123456, script prepends n to logon_id selected from table2 e.g. n123456 to match it against table1 for updating. I can update but then I cannot look back at table2 to delete the record as the login_id is now different.

Comment: changed the query so try it out and tell me how it works also added a query to remove the n from the login_id on table1 also the last new query has better performance if you choose to remove the n from login_id.